# Uniform Hashing. Understanding space occupancy and choice of functions

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, space-complexity, hash-tables, hashing

I'm having troubles understanding two things from some notes about Uniform Hashing.
Here's the copy-pasted part of the notes:

> Let us first argue by a counting argument why the uniformity property,
> we required to good hash functions, is computationally hard to
> guarantee. Recall that we are interested in hash functions which map
> keys in $U$ to integers in $\{0, 1, ..., m-1\}$. The total number of such
> hash functions is $m^{|U|}$, given that each key among the $|U|$ ones can be
> mapped into $m$ slots of the hash table. **In order to guarantee uniform
> distribution of the keys and independence among them, our hash
> function should be anyone of those ones.** But, in this case, its
> representation would need $\Omega(log_2 m^{|U|}) = \Omega(|U| log_2 m)$ bits, which is
> really too much in terms of space occupancy and in the terms of
> computing time (i.e. it would take at least $\Omega(\frac{|U|log_2 m}{log_2 |U|})$ time to just
> read the hash encoding).

The part I put in bold is the first thing is confusing me.

*Why the function should be any one of those? Shouldn't you avoid a good part of them, like the ones sending every element from the universe $U$ into the same number and thus not distributing the elements?*

The second thing is the last "$\Omega$". *Why would it take $\Omega(\frac{|U|log_2 m}{log_2 |U|})$  time just to read the hash encoding?*

The numerator is the number of bits needed to index every hash function in the space of such functions, the denominator is the size in bits of a key. Why this ratio gives a lower bound on the time needed to read the encoding? And what hash encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we sample a hash function $h$ at random from a collection $\mathcal{H}\subseteq [m]^U$ (we denote by $[m]$ the set $\{0,1,...,m-1\}$). The best possible thing we can require from this choice is that $\left(h(x_1),h(x_2),....,h(x_{|u|})\right)$ are jointly uniformly distributed over $[m]^U$, where $U=\{x_1,...,x_{|U|}\}$ (this in turn implies independence). Fix some $h_0\in [m]^U$, then under the previous requirement we have:

$\Pr\limits_{h\sim\mathcal{H}}[h=h_0]=\Pr\limits_{h\sim\mathcal{H}}\left[h(x_1)=h_0(x_1)\land...\land h(x_{|U|})=h_0(x_{|U|})\right]=\frac{1}{m^{|U|}}$.

It follows that $h$ is uniformly distributed over all possible functions in $[m]^U$ (in any other case we will fail either in uniformity or in independence). This is what is meant by "$h$ should be anyone of these functions".

Comment: The thing I don't get is why are we talking about the time it takes to read a function and not the time it takes to compute it

Comment: I'm removing the second part of my answer, as it's obviously false (encoding of an element in $U$ requires $\log U$ bits, but repeatedly asking for $h(x)$ for all $x\in U$ where each value requires time $T$ to compute takes $|U|T$ time and not $T\log |U|$. Since we can generate a truly random $h$ by sampling a uniform binary string of length $U\log m$ where $h(x_i)$ is given by the $i$'th block of size $\log m$, which makes reading $h(x)$ easy, I'm not sure what is meant here. Perhaps you can link the full text to clarify.